# How to trim filename extension, replace hyphens with spaces, and start each word with a capital?

Tags: php, filenames, explode, uppercase

I have a string like this:

```
$image = 'galaxy-s6.jpg';
```

I want to trim the `.jpg`, and replace the `-` with the `space`, and make the first letter of each word uppercase like this:

```
Galaxy S6
```

I tried

```
$name  = str_replace('.jpg', '', $image);
$name  = str_replace('-', ' ', $name);
array_map('ucfirst', explode(' ', $name));
```

I got

```
galaxy s6
```

Any hints for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ucwords()` function:

```
<?php

    $image = 'galaxy-s6.jpg';
    $name  = str_replace('.jpg', '', $image);
    $name  = str_replace('-', ' ', $name);
    echo ucwords($name);

?>
```

- `$name  = str_replace('.jpg', '', $image);` will replace `.jpg` with a blank.
- `$name  = str_replace('-', ' ', $name);` will replace `-` with a blank.
- `echo ucwords($name);` will capitalise the first letter of each word (`galaxy` and `s6`)

**Alternatively**, you can also explode the last part of the filename, `.jpg` or any other file extension and remove it, using `explode()` function:

```
<?php

    $image = 'galaxy-s6.jpg';
    $name = explode(".", $image);
    $name  = str_replace('-', ' ', $name[0]);
    echo ucwords($name);

?>
```

Thus, both methods will echo `Galaxy S6`.

Comment: You shouldn't really remove the extension like that, you should explicitly look for ".jpg" *at the end of the string*.

Comment: What if there's more than one `.` in the name?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> array_map('ucfirst', explode(' ', $name));
> ```

The only issue here is that you're ignoring the return value of `array_map`. This would do it:

```
echo join(' ', array_map('ucfirst', explode(' ', $name)));
```

However, an overall saner approach is this:

```
echo ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_FILENAME)));
```

See:

- http://php.net/pathinfo
- http://php.net/ucwords

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$string = "galaxy-s6.jpg";
$exploded = explode(".",$string);
$replace = str_replace("-", " ", $exploded[0]);
$upper = ucwords($replace);

echo $upper;
```

**Result:**

```
Galaxy S6
```

**Explanation:**

- explode for exploding with (.)
- replace - with space
- get 0 index from exploded array
- As @deceze suggest no need to ucfirst just use ucwords() for capital letter.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

For suppose if you have (.) between your file name than `explode()` will fail in this case you can handle this by using `preg_replace();`

```
// your string
$string = "galaxy-s6.jpg";

// replace after .
$removed = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $string);

// replace - between file name
$replace = str_replace("-", " ", $removed);

// ucwords for first letter capital
$upper = ucwords($replace);

echo $upper;
```

Comment: I want to make each pieces capitalize not just my first one.

Comment: Why `ucfirst` *and* `ucwords`...? Seems redundant.

Comment: @deceze: ucfirst only capatilize Galaxy, but ucwords will capatilize S6

Comment: What if there's a `.` in the filename before the extension?

Comment: @deceze: i am using preg_replace for this case., answer updated.

Comment: I don't know why everyone needs to reinvent the wheel for parsing filename extensions... http://stackoverflow.com/a/35604119/476

Comment: @deceze: pathinfo($string, PATHINFO_FILENAME); wonderfull, thanks for sharing this...

Answer (score 1):

Just few functions :

```
<?php
$a = "galaxy-s6.jpg";
$a = str_replace(".jpg","",$a);
$a = str_replace("-"," ",$a);
echo ucwords($a)
?>
```

Demo : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/213abb52e2aed4265c5bc1af45c544559ae9757f

Comment:  If the string was hardcoded and never changed, you'd think OP would just hardcode "Galaxy S6" as well, wouldn't you?!

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code:

```
 $string = 'galaxy-s6.jpg';
 $name = str_replace('.jpg', '', $string);
 $name = str_replace('-', ' ', $name);
 $name = explode(' ', $name);
 foreach ($name as $key => $value) {
      $name[$key] = ucfirst($value);
 }
 $name = implode(' ', $name);
 echo $name;// => Galaxy S6
```